# Debugging Angular1 select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I've used Angular1 selects before, but am having a wild time untangling what's breaking a select I'm working with at the moment.

Here's the template for the select I'm trying to build:

```
<div class="dropdown-selector-container">
  <select
    class="dropdown-select"
    data-ng-options="option.sectionId as option.label for option in dropdownOptions"
    data-ng-model="selectedSection"
    data-ng-change="setDropdownOption()">
  </select>
</div>
```

The object and method in the controller look like this:

```
$scope.dropdownOptions = [
  {
    'label': 'ok',
    'sectionId': '1',
  },
  {
    'label': 'wow',
    'sectionId': '2',
  }
];

$scope.setDropdownOption = function() {
  console.log($scope);
};
```

A working fiddle of the intended behavior is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dduhaime/1an3qd38/).

The trouble is, when I replicate the code from the fiddle in a [template](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/gathering-a-building/blob/dropdown-selectors/templates/partials/layout/dropdown-selector.html) and [controller](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/gathering-a-building/blob/dropdown-selectors/assets/js/app.js#L594) within a route in my [development instance](http://gathering-a-building-deploy.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/#/routes/architecture-and-urbanism) (where the dropdown is only visible on viewports with width 800px or fewer), the $state object printed by the controller function does not contain a `selectedSection` key:

[image]

Does anyone know why that might be the case? I would be very grateful for any advice you can offer!

Comment: For debugging angularjs, I highly recommend this [addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) for chrome

Comment: Oh, you're using it already I think

Comment: Yes, thank you! I  also just discovered that `angular.element(".dropdown-selector-container select").scope()` (from the console) gives me direct insight into my target element's scope. The element has the `selectedSection` scope object, it's just not propagating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this was learning that one can inspect the scope of an element from the console with something like `angular.element(".dropdown-selector-container select").scope()`. This led me to a solution:

I noticed the dropdownOptions object was present in the controller scope, so I set the data-ng-model to `dropdownOptions.selected`, and on change I can now interact with this value.

React makes this kind of inheritance so much nicer...